# question marks instead of citations / extended problem

Tags: citing, natbib

I am having trouble with generating references. For some citations instead of authors names the file generates question marks. I tried the suggested found in this forum and already I am aware for the "compile - double compile" process but no progress.

Can someone help me?

Here is parts of my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{2} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks,urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
For a survey see \citet{Perotti2008} who...
A leading example is \citet{Papageorgiou2012} who

\newpage 

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

The bibliography file contains the following entries

```
@TECHREPORT{ Perotti2008,
title = {In Search of the Transmission Mechanism of Fiscal Policy},
author = {Hill, Scott and Wootters, William K.}
booktitle = {NBER Macroeconomics Annual 2007",}
volume = {22},
publisher = {National Bureau of Economic Research}
year = {1997},
}

@ARTICLE{Papageorgiou2012,
  author = {Papageorgiou Dimitris},
  title = {Fiscal Policy Reforms in General Equilibrium: The case of Greece},
  journal = {Journal of Macroecnomics},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {34},
  pages = {504-522},
  owner = {Minamar},
  timestamp = {2012.08.03}
}
```

Comment: Your entries are faulty, commas are missing after some fields and in booktitle there is a single quote and the comma is inside the braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ulrike said in her comment, you have some errors in your `bib` file.

A little explanation: Each entry of your `bib` file has to be build like this:

```
@literature{key,
  name  = {value(s)},
  name1 = {value(s)},
  ...
  namen = {value(s)}
}
```

`literature` can be `book`, `article` etc., `key` is the citation key, `name` stands for the name of a field entry like `author`, `title` etc. and `value(s)` represent the values of the field entry, the name of the author, the book title etc. Each line has to be ended with an comma (outside the }), exept the last one, there you can write a comma or not. Writing not a comma causes often errors when you add a new line.

So your corrected part of the `bib` file with a little bit pretty printing should look like you can see in the updated MWE.

**Update:**

The following MWE runs on my system without any error or warning:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}           % allows overwriting of file
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@TECHREPORT{Perotti2008,
  title       = {In Search of the Transmission Mechanism of Fiscal Policy},
  author      = {Hill, Scott and Wootters, {William K.}},
  booktitle   = {NBER Macroeconomics Annual 2007},
  volume      = {22},
  publisher   = {National Bureau of Economic Research},
  institution = {National Bureau of Economic Research??????},
  year        = {1997},
}

@ARTICLE{Papageorgiou2012,
  author    = {Papageorgiou, Dimitris},
  title     = {Fiscal Policy Reforms in General Equilibrium: The case of Greece},
  journal   = {Journal of Macroecnomics},
  year      = {2012},
  volume    = {34},
  pages     = {504--522},
  owner     = {Minamar},
  timestamp = {2012.08.03},
}
@ARTICLE{Edenber1999,
  author  = {Edenberg, Wendy and Martin Eichenbaum and DM Fischer},
  title   = {Understanding the Effects of Shocks to Government Purchases},
  journal = {Review of Economic Dynamics},
  year    = {1999},
  pages   = {166--206},
  owner   = {Minamar},
  timestamp = {2012.03.03}
}

@UNPUBLISHED{Leeper2008,
  author = {Leeper, E. M. and Walker, {T. B.} and S.-C S.Yang},
  title  = {Fiscal foresight: Analytics and econometrics},
  month  = {May},
  year   = {2008},
  owner  = {Minamar},
  timestamp = {2012.08.05}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
For a survey see \citet{Perotti2008} who~\dots
A leading example is \citet{Papageorgiou2012} who~\dots
%\nocite{*}   % all entrys in bibliography to test the bib file

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Use this example to test your `bib` entrys. Just copy **one** of your entry into the MWE and run it again (remeber: three times).

**Update 2**:

I added two corrected entrys of your bibliography in the MWE. The article entry `Edenber1999` has a lot of problems in the author field. I tryed to correct it. Please check by your own. The entry `Leeper2008` shows another problem: write authors either "Name, Firstname" or "Firstname Name". Don't mix it.  Better include the complete firstnames of the authors. Have a look on Author Yang (blank missing: `S. Yang`?). Do not use `\&` instead of `and`.

Comment: I indeed noticed those faulty entries. I made the changes but still i am having trouble seeing my references on the text. I provided these two references, because while the second it shows up the first does not. I really have trouble. I checked the syntax all the time, compiled the files numerous times but still no progress. I am still receiving the "citations undefined" without understanding what is the problem.

Comment: I added a MWE to my answer to help you. Have you found the warnings in the `blg`file?

Comment: here is it i made a zip code as suggested. Hope it helps. [link](http://www.filedropper.com/desktop_7)

Comment: Did it worked with you ? because in my case the problem persists. I even deleted this reference but again no progress. You think that could be subtle syntax errors here and there ?

Comment: Ok, I will try to have a look again. Actually the bibliography was generated by a software. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: I will try different editor then. I guess is because i am very new to this forum my reputation is that low. Thanks for the support ;)